# Find max volume and data count above that volume in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a sample dataframe as below. I need to find result as per the below condition.

```
Datetime             Volume       Price
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1033         504
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1960         516
2020-08-05 09:15:00     0         521
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1724         520
2020-08-05 09:15:00     0         500
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1870         540
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1024         476
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1980         548
2020-08-05 09:20:00     0         551
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1426         526
2020-08-05 09:20:00     0         586
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1968         518
```

1. Find Price at Maximum Volume with group-by on Datetime Column.
2. Calculate how many Price Values are above Price of Sl No 1 (ignoring rows with zero volume)

I want my result dataframe as below:

```
Datetime             Volume       Price  Count_abv_prc
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1960         516    2
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1980         548    0
```

For Datetime = 2020-08-05 09:15:00, only two values are above 516 (520 and 540) and
for Datetime = 2020-08-05 09:20:00, no values are above 548 (ignoring rows with zero volume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
# positive volume
pos_vol = df.query('Volume!=0')

# rows with max volume by time
s = pos_vol.groupby('Datetime').Volume.idxmax()

# extract the output
out = df.loc[s].set_index(['Datetime'])

# map the datetime to the price corresponding to the max volume 
aligned_prc = pos_vol['Datetime'].map(out['Price'])

# count by datetime
out['Count_abv'] = (pos_vol['Price'].gt(aligned_prc)
                    .groupby(pos_vol['Datetime']).sum()
                   )
```

Output:

```
                     Volume  Price  Count_abv
Datetime                                     
2020-08-05 09:15:00    1960    516          2
2020-08-05 09:20:00    1980    548          0
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. Nice reply. One more query. If I want to know count below that price. How to approach ?

Comment: @Pravat for below that price instead of `gt` use `lt` (less than)