# Filter data with specific condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to find result as per the below condition from the sample dataframe given below:

| Datetime | Volume | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-08-05 09:15:00 | 1033 | 504 |
| 2020-08-05 09:15:00 | 1960 | 516 |
| 2020-08-05 09:15:00 | 0 | 450 |
| 2020-08-05 09:15:00 | 1724 | 520 |
| 2020-08-05 09:15:00 | 0 | 500 |
| 2020-08-05 09:15:00 | 1870 | 540 |
| 2020-08-05 09:20:00 | 1024 | 476 |
| 2020-08-05 09:20:00 | 1980 | 548 |
| 2020-08-05 09:20:00 | 0 | 480 |
| 2020-08-05 09:20:00 | 1426 | 526 |
| 2020-08-05 09:20:00 | 0 | 586 |
| 2020-08-05 09:20:00 | 1968 | 588 |

1. Find Price at Maximum Volume with group-by on Datetime Column.
2. Calculate how many Price Values are below Price of Sl No 1 (ignoring rows with zero volume)

I want my result dataframe as below:

```
Datetime             Volume       Price  Count_below_prc
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1960         516    1
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1980         548    2
```

> For Datetime = 2020-08-05 09:15:00, only one value is below 516 (504,
> ignoring rows with zero volume) for Datetime = 2020-08-05 09:20:00,
> two values are below 548 (476 & 526, ignoring rows with zero volume)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find max volume and data count above that volume in a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609882/find-max-volume-and-data-count-above-that-volume-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: Yea. But How to execute for values below that price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `groupby` and `apply`

```
def func(row):
    x = (row[row['Volume']==max(row['Volume'])])
    x['Count_below_prc']=(row.loc[row['Price'].lt(x['Price'].values[0]) & row['Volume'].ne(0), 'Price'].count())
    return x

res = df.groupby('Datetime',as_index=False).apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**res:**

|  | Datetime | Volume | Price | Count_below_prc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-08-05 09:15:00 | 1960 | 516 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-08-05 09:20:00 | 1980 | 548 | 2 |

Comment: Thanks Mam. I liked your approach on this problem. Can You help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609882/find-max-volume-and-data-count-above-that-volume-in-a-dataframe